# Clarify Flagging History Stats

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, flag-history

Right now the flagging history stats are kind of lumped together visually. I'd like to suggest an easy to implement enhancement that would make reading the flagging history stats easier.

By adding some basic visual cues like borders, and placing the percentage statistic after the particular flag type, your history becomes much easier to read at a glance.

[image]

Comment: If we're on the subject of clarifying the stats, can we drop the "deemed" from "deemed helpful" and change the "waiting for review" to "active" as well?

Comment: Huh. Looking at the declined/disputed rates; it kinda makes me wonder if I'm just overly cautious about my flags.

Comment: @Dennis When it comes to flags, a little bit of declined flagging is preferable if more bad questions are captured in the net.

Comment: Just wondering. I'm at 195 helpful to 2 declined right now.

Comment: @animuson BTW "deemed" has disappeared with this fix.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Oded](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/140505/oded) was nice enough to implement this in the latest build.  We don't have percentages, but we've added an indicator/underline for each category. The history now looks like:

> [image]

Comment: It also includes flags that were aged away (mine being quite a high number, too).

Comment: @Jamal Yes, it sure does - I'm going through a lot of posts to complete them, including [this one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300937/can-we-get-a-stat-to-show-how-many-flags-have-aged-away).

Comment: Cool, thanks @Oded. I'll keep my fingers crossed for the percentages.

Comment: @j08691  Still interested in seeing the percentages? I wrote a [userscript](https://stackapps.com/questions/6773/flagging-percentages) for it..