# Feedback/suggestions for new flagging page in user profile

Tags: discussion, profile-page, flag-history, feedback

Recently the flagging page of the user profile received an overhaul:

[image: Overhaul of new flagging history page]

Do you have any feedback or suggestions for these changes?

Comment: I like it. What did the old look like?

Comment: @KevinB [here you go](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ujjPx.png) (from [Can we improve the flagging history filters UI?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/310690/398063))

Answer (score 18):

This is minor, but when I first saw the new design, I thought the `>` was a dropdown. (Compare the dropdowns in the [10k tools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rD40E.png).) Therefore, I think the arrow should be a different character, maybe a bullet point.

> [image]

Comment: I had the same response. I've been trained that arrows/triangles open/close menus. That said, this choice was intentional as it's used elsewhere on the network in the same way. I'm not saying it's a great choice - but if we're trying to follow the standards set for the network's appearance, this meets that standard. Presumably, (if it works properly) if/when we decide to change this standard, it will change everywhere that uses it, which is why Stacks is important moving forward. We make one change to Stacks and it fixes issues like this everywhere.

Comment: I'm not wild about this either, but as Cat sez there's a certain value in being consistent here; the only reason I messed with this in the first place was that it was using a unique styling that seemed to lead to more confusion than it should've. Let's give it some time to soak in & see how much confusion results.

Answer (score 7):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug), also [reported separately](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/319779/162102) because there was a request to report bugs in responsive design via that tag.

**Page is *mostly* responsive, but titles aren't paying attention to boundaries.**

I see this on my flag-summary page:

[image: pink backgrounds overflow into stats block]

At first I thought this was because not all pages on the site are responsive yet, but this one (otherwise) seems to be.  The stuff on the main part of the page re-lays itself out as I change the window size, and there's no horizontal scroll.  However, question titles don't follow this rule and the pink backgrounds from deleted questions overshoot the text.

Long *flag* text (using a custom flag) wraps; it's just the titles and the pink they bring along with them that's not minding the boundaries.  I suspect that individual elements on that page have wrap directives and it got missed on titles.

Comment: yeah, the bulk of the content on that page - and on the flag history page which uses the same renderer - are ugly as sin. I'm all about redesigning that, but it'll take a bit more thought than the nav sidebar; might ping you for feedback if you're open to it.

Comment: @Shog9 I'm happy to provide feedback.  I agree that the page could do with a bigger overhaul; meanwhile, this *seems* like a smaller bug (but I am not a web developer and could well be wrong).

Comment: Not to be petty, but... I got a 30" screen; I got no personal reason to care. So if I'm gonna touch this, I'm gonna fix as many complaints as possible, 'cause otherwise I'll end up spending 10x as long handling further feedback threads like this than I will actually changing anything.

Comment: @Shog9 ah, ok -- many developers are more open to the small fix than the big fix (or big pile of small fixes); didn't know which camp you were in.  I'm happy to talk page design; just ping me somewhere.

Comment: Small fixes have their place. But there's also a cost to testing, and... There's a cost to *change* - even small changes have a chance of disrupting someone's workflow. The more bang for the buck you get on every set of changes, the easier it is to justify the time spent testing, the time spent re-learning, re-documenting...

Comment: This particular page - obscure though it is - relies on a bit of code and associated styling that's shared by two pages: one moderator-only (flags against a user), and one (the one under discussion) shared by every user who checks their flag stats - only one needs this change, but both would need to be tested, so it'd be nice if both could benefit from the effort - there are already several bugs open regarding the styling and information available (or lack thereof...) - any time invested in solving these would then get testing free. I'm thinking… Something closer to the timeline view of flags.

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean about the mod page.  It doesn't have anything in the right column like the page here, so there's no overlap like in my screenshots, but I see the long pink bars there too.  I'm not following your timeline idea; which timeline do you mean?  I'm having trouble seeing how to apply either post timelines or the flags section of the mod-dashboard user page to flag history, which means I'm missing something.

Comment: Yeah, I need to do some mockups; I'm not sure a literal copy would work, but essentially my hope is that by standardizing the positioning of the various attributes of each post, flag, and flag result we could make the pages easier to scan - make it easier to identify specific flags or responses of interest without having to scan each word of each line along the way.

Comment: Standardized positioning is a big help.  I always grit my teeth when looking at comment flags in the post timeline because of what that does to the layout... hard to navigate after that!  Yeah, let's think about how to unify these pages' designs to make all of them better.

Comment: Heh... Pretty sure I fixed that a bit ago - have you checked it recently? But yeah... For a long while it was pretty bad. The bit that I like about the timeline - or that ToC script I wrote for you - is simply that I never have to hunt for anything; assuming I have one piece of information and need related pieces, there's a clear, consistent place to look for that. I think a lot of the frustration with the flag summary comes from not being sure what you're looking at: information isn't labeled consistently, it moves around, it's implicit in color or font size, it's altogether missing.

Comment: Oh, you did fix that -- thanks!  I don't need to be afraid of that expander any more. :-)  And yes, agreed on both the timeline and the flag TOC; they both make it easy to scan or (in the case of comments) click down the page (delete, delete, delete, ok, delete...).  So with both of these the containing unit is the *post*; in the case of flag history and the (mod) user-flags page the containing unit is a *collection of flaggable things*, so we need to figure out how to apply the consistency of the former to the latter.  I'll think about mockups too.

Answer (score 4):

Call me blind but I find it hard to easily distinguish the flag categories. The titles (post flags/spam flags etc) are written in the same font, same font weight than the subsections, and there is no spacing or line separator between the categories.

True, selecting one does bolden the font and puts a color marker next to it, but I think it would be better to space the categories a little bit to begin with, as well as maybe already boldening the font, and keeping the color marker (or some highlighting) for when the category is selected.

Here's a quick draft, and here's [a gif switching between the two](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uWoSx.gif):

> [image: new proposal, with categories boldened]

Comment: I don't hate this. My only concern is that it might make it harder to discern which top-level category is selected