# Flag-summary page is *mostly* responsive, but post titles overflow into the stats box

Tags: bug, design, flag-history, responsive-design

I see this on my flag-summary page:

[image: pink backgrounds overflow into stats block]

At first I thought this was because not all pages on the site are responsive yet, but this one (otherwise) seems to be.  The stuff on the main part of the page re-lays itself out as I change the window size, and there's no horizontal scroll.  Here it is in a smaller window:

[image: smaller window, even more overflow]

The flags at the top of my list are on deleted posts so at first I thought this was just about the pink background (which is sometimes way longer than the title), but here's that smaller window farther down.  The red line indicates where the summary box (the right column) would start if it reached down that far:

[image: long titles]

Long flag text (like in the second screenshot) wraps; it's just the titles and the pink they bring along with them that's not minding the boundaries.  I suspect that individual elements on that page have wrap directives and it got missed on titles.

Comment: Not to sound preachy, but wouldn't it be easier to track all these by posting them in the [feedback thread](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/319759/398063)? (Although I'm not sure if it has any kind of "official" status)

Comment: @Jenayah if I had seen that question (I wonder how I missed it), I would have.  Hmm, written like an official request for feedback but not from an employee, and not specifically about the responsiveness angle, but I guess I should move this over there.

Comment: Added [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/319780/162102).

Comment: @Jenayah that is not official feedback post, i.e. not posted by SE staff. There is a very good chance it will be missed/ignored by those who can handle it. Personally I wouldn't post feedback on non official feedback request. Like with all other things, bugs should be reported one by one as we find them.

Comment: @ShadowWizard nonetheless, this current bug report may have been missed. ;0

Comment: @Cœur not really, the team says repeatedly they do see all bugs, and due to lack of time and resources, can't handle them all or even reply to all. So minor bugs like this can take years to be fixed, and even non minor bugs like allowing animated avatar take months to years to be fixed. They just have more important things to do, which is expected.

Comment: Fwiw, I haven't forgotten about this... There's another PR that touches a lot of the same stuff but in other places; I'm hoping it lands soon, so that I can steal from it or at least avoid stepping on toes.

Comment: @Shog9 Do you know what happened? Did it land?

Comment: Probably, @randomperson - the core issue here is a very old post summary renderer, which has certainly been redone at least a couple times since this post (separately for flag lists and for primary post lists). But... Updates not being used for the flag summary, and may not be suitable for it.