# New flag overview UI - "dropdown-arrows" used but there's no dropdown action

Tags: feature-request, design, flags, user-interface

The UI in the flags overview has received an update with some nice design love, and it looks good.

The only thing that bothers me a little is that there's these arrow-style icons (`>`) in the menu that feel like they expand a level below that level in the menu, however there is no collapsing/expanding in this menu.

[image]

Will there be collapsing/expanding in this menu in the future? If so, could the arrows be hidden if there's nothing to expand? If not, could the arrows be removed or changed to an icon that does not indicate expanding/collapsing behavior?

Comment: related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/319765/369802